# Apache simple redirect from one page to a second one

Tags: apache, redirect

I need to redirect from one url to another full url

all examples I have seen use reg expressions and complicated syntax
I need to redirect from

www.mydomain.com/page1.html

to

www.mydomain.com/page1replacement.html

I suppose its in the .htaccess file, but what would be the syntax?

**Update1**
Tried this but its not working: Do I need to restart apache??

```
Redirect 301 http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=100&q=1022&x=0&y=0 http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=1022&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&free_shipping=&category=100
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes into your .htaccess file. Full URLs can be used.

```
Redirect 301 /page1.html http://mydomain.com/page1replacement.html
```

Comment: If you need to do GET parameter processing, it's better to redirect with PHP instead of using Apache because Apache's redirects are very general. Have you tried clearing your cache before refreshing? Another reason could be because you're using `[]` in your get parameters. Try redirecting without the special characters.