# PHP Redirect, how to?

Tags: php, apache, magento, redirect

For some reason one magento url is not working fine on my website.
see here:
[Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'position' in order clause is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298533/integrity-constraint-violation-1052-column-position-in-order-clause-is-ambigu)

So, I decided that I could do a redirect for this failing url:
I tried with apache but it doesnt work
see here:
[Apache simple redirect from one page to a second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13463282/apache-simple-redirect-from-one-page-to-a-second-one)

They suggested to do it with php

can someone pls explain me how to do this with php?

something like

```
if url = 'myfaliingurl' then
  redirect to new url
```

thats it

this is what I tried in apache

```
Redirect 301 http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=100&q=1022&x=0&y=0 http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=1022&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&free_shipping=&category=100
```

**Update 1:**

Its not working, I put this on index.php at the end.

```
if($url == 'http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=100&q=1022&x=0&y=0')
  {
          header('location:http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=100&q=1022&x=0&y=0 http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=1022&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&free_shipping=&category=100');
          exit();
  }
else
{
Mage::run('printerdepo','website');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this code you get

```
 <?php
  if($url == 'myfaliingurl')
  {
          header('location:http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/result/index/?cat=100&q=1022&x=0&y=0 http://www.theprinterdepo.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?name=1022&sku=&price%5Bfrom%5D=&price%5Bto%5D=&free_shipping=&category=100');
  }
  else{
          header('location:otherposition');
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: should I put this on index.php?

Comment: shold I also put exit() as other said?

Comment: yeah, anywhere you want because it's base on condition!

Comment: there are no required exit() because whenever redirect then after header code that will never execute!!!

Comment: Of course you need `exit()`. The code *will* continue executing, even though the header was sent. The fact that you send the header has nothing to do with the rest of the script.

Comment: lol, I think I am missing set the $url variable, how can I do that? $url = currenturl?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to use PHP you can use `header()`

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
```

so:

```
if (/*whatever you're checking*/){
    header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use the `header()` function to redirect a request:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I dont know php syntax, please elaborate the answer more.

Comment: The manual I linked to explains it perfectly. You just need to include that line wherever/whenever you want it to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is written like this: Remember not to output anything before the php `header()` function.

```
$url = "myfailingurl";
$newurl = "http://www.mynewurl.com/blabla";

if ($url == "myfailingurl"){
     header("Location: $newurl"); die();
}
```

More details about the `header()` function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

With PHP is like this:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
// if you get a header error, which is really frequent, try with javascript like this:
echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location ="http://www.example.com";</script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(url == 'myfaliingurl')
   redirect('newUrl');


function redirect($url)
{
   header("Location: $url");
}
```